# Get subset of results from sorted set randomly instead of lexicological? - Redis

Tags: redis

I have a sorted set with a key "Name", the values are names, and the score is the date the name was added to "Name".

Right now I'm doing `ZRANGEBYSCORE` to get 25 names that were added on a specific date and it seems I can only get the output in alphabetical format.  Is there any possible way to randomize the output from Redis?

Ex:  Instead of getting "Albert", "Andy", "April" I'd like to get "Greg", "Albert", "Josh".

It doesn't matter if the answer is messy or hacked together, just need to accomplish this somehow. (without exporting all results for a date and sorting them randomly outside of Redis)

Comment: Yes, by using a server-side Lua script.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by using `ZCOUNT` to get the number of values for the score, diving it by 25, then doing 25 `ZRANGEBYSCORE` calls with a limit and offset.